# How to close the console after start a program with `system` function?

Tags: c++

I want to start firefox using c++, then close my program. So I use:

```
system("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe\"");
return 0;
```

But, the process don't close. So I try to kill the process by itself, but it was fail. So, I figure out that the `system` function is still running when firefox was started (Like `cin` function). So, how can I do it?

Comment: U can use the batch or python for this, it's better and flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
system("start \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe\"");
//      ^^^^^
return 0;
```

It is solution for your problem.

Comment: You may want to highilght that you added `start` at the beginning of the command

Comment: Federico klez Culloca you right, I new in stackoverfow, can I highlight it just inside code example?

Comment: I'd just state that in your answer, like "use `start` to run the program"

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. It will show a command line with the header is a path to firefox.exe. The program will close but it doesn't start firefox.

Comment: Thế Hải Nguyễn, it works for me, however I use chrome and my command is  'start chrome.exe'

Comment: You also can try to add firefox folder to path and call 'start firefox.exe'

Comment: Ok, It worked. I just call 'start firefox.exe' and don't add anything to path. Thank you very much